# Sum of reciprocals of primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

If $p_i$ is an infinite set of distinct primes such that $c=\sum\frac{1}{p_i} < \infty$, must $c$ be a transcendental number?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. Pick any positive algebraic number, and by choosing your primes carefully, you can make the infinite series converge to your number.

Comment: Is it obvious that this can be done ? Could you give a reference to a book/article discussing this ? Thanks!

Comment: The sum $\sum \frac{1}{p_i}$ diverges. So for any $k$, the sums $\sum_{k}^{k+n}\frac{1}{p_i}$ are unbounded. Also, the $\frac{1}{p_i}$ approach $0$. That's all we need. Pick any positive real $x$. Add up enough $\frac{1}{p_i}$ so that we get within $1$ of $x$, but below it. Then add  enough more $\frac{1}{p_i}$ so we get within $1/2$ of $x$, but below it. And so on.

Comment: @Andre thanks. Indeed, this proves that if $a_i$ are positive and approaching zero with divergent sum then there's a subseries converging to any given positive real.